# What is the best implementation of a ignore case dictionary In C#

Tags: c#, comparative-review, hash-map

Imagine we have a custom dictionary class which is derived from `Dictionary<string, object>`. Dictionary is ***case-insensitive*** about keys and elements arrange is not important.
So what is the most optimized way to compare two instance of this class, or in another word what is the best override of
`Equals` method in this class.

I tried to use these two ways to implement this class. But i'm not sure which way is better than the other.
Please help me to choose the best way or correct me if i made any mistake.

*First implementation:*

```
public class CustomeDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public CustomeDictionary() :
     base(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
    }

    public CustomeDictionary(CustomeDictionary CustomeDictionary) :
     base(CustomeDictionary, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomeDictionary other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        if (Count != other.Count)
            return false;

        foreach (var (key, value) in this)
            if (!other.ContainsKey(key) || !value.Equals(other[key]))
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as CustomeDictionary);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Sum(i => (i.Key.ToLower(), i.Value).GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

*The second way* was to use another class which is an implementation of
`IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` which can help to use some efficient Linq methods like
`Except` to override the `Equals` and overload `==`.

The EqualityComparer CustomClass

```
public class CustomKeyValuePair : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, object> x, KeyValuePair<string, object> y)
        => x.Equals(y);

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, object> obj)
    {
        var (key, value) = obj;
        return (key.ToLower(), value).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and I have used it like below in Equals:

```
   public bool Equals(CustomHashTable other)
   {
      return this.Except(other, new CustomKeyValuePair()).Any();
   }
```

Please help me to improve and refactor the code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. We can provide suggestions on how to improve the code, however, we can't help you refactor the code.

Comment: Why not using the `Comparer` instead ? it's already implemented in the dictionary class, and your class inherited it already.

Comment: What benefit would either have over standard data-constructs?

Comment: @pacmaninbw
that would be very helpful for me, thanks

Comment: What not just use  `var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: @RickDavin because we need some kinda structure and we re not able to use it, we need a custom structure, please